# JMS queue - 10 second pause between sending and receiving object message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have two applications within my server, and use JMS via ActiveMQ to send messages between the two. My two apps are as follows

Web service - accepts HTTP requests,  validates, then sends messages to be executed by the other application.

Exec App - accepts object messages, executes order, sends execution report back to the web service to present to the client.

My Exec app receives messages from the Web service within 200ms, no problems there. However when I send an exec report, the message can hang in the queue for over 10 seconds before being received by the web service. I am using the same code for both side's consumers so I am unsure what the cause would be.

Here is my message producer in the Exec App -

```
public void createAndSendExecReport(OrderExecutionReport theReport){
    try {
        logger.debug("Posting exec report: " +theReport.getOrderId());
        this.excChannelMessageProducer.send(createMessage(theReport));
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[there is a createMessage method which converts my POJO into an object message]

```
 MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                logger.debug("Incoming execution report");
                try {
                    OrderExecutionReport report = (OrderExecutionReport)((ObjectMessage)message).getObject();
                    consumeExecutionReport(report);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Message handling failed. Caught: " + e);
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    logger.error(sw.toString());
                }
            }
        };
```

I get the log message "sending execution report"
Then nothing in the web service for up to 15 seconds later until finally I get "incoming ... "

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: is your activeMQ using scheduling of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough MDBs running on the Exec App so they can handle the load.